# Array of pointers to a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

does anyone know why this docent work? is it just the syntax that you an leave out the second index or why is it that you can't set the pointer to the first element of the second row?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};   // A 2x3 array of int values
    int* ptrArray[2];  // An array of 2 pointers to int

    ptrArray[0] = array[0]; // The first pointer points to the first row of the 2D array
    ptrArray[1] = array[1]; // The second pointer points to the second row of the 2D array

    // Accessing the second row via ptrArray[1]
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << ptrArray[1][i] << " "; // Displays the values of the second row
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`ptrArray[0]` is set to `array[0]` and it does work but shouldn't it actually be `array[0][1]`? or at least `array[4]` because multidimensional arrays are stored in linear order?

I know that arrays are not part of the c++-standard and there are different ways to approach this but I want to understand the topic.
Thanks

Comment: This is because array decays to pointer to their first element. See dupe: [What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay). It's called **array to pointer decay**

Comment: *I know that arrays are not part of the c++-standard* -- Arrays have always been part of the C++ language.

Comment: `array[0]` is  an array of type `int[3]` which **decays** to `int*`. See the dupe. So basically you're assigning `int*` to `int*` which is perfectly fine. I would also recommend a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as this is explained in any such beginner book.

Comment: Note that `array[0][1]` would be an `int`, while `array[4]` would be out of bounds.

Comment: @user12002570 but `array[0]` is not an array of type `int[2][3]` as declared above. I don't understand why one can just write for example `array[1]` and the second row ( the fourth element) is meant.

Comment: @Ramyz Both `array[0]` and `array[1]` are of type `int[3]` and they both **decay** to `int*`. This is how multidimensional array work and is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Note also that stackoverflow is not an "introduction to c++ arrays" so a book should be preferred to clear the basics.